# Как отправить файл с русским именем через telegram бота

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, requests

Пытаюсь отправить файл с русскоязычным именем используя python и библиотеку request следующим образом:

```
url = 'https://api.telegram.org/token/sendAudio?chat_id=chat_id'
files = {'audio': open('тест.mp3', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

И получаю ошибку

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":413,"description":"Request Entity Too Large"}
```

Файлы с английским именем отправляются без проблем.
Есть идеи как это можно решить?

Comment: Имя тут совершенно не причем, особенно если посмотреть на текст ошибки. Возникает вопрос, какого размера файл? https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files "10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for other files." - могу предположить, что аудиофайл больше 50мб.

Comment: @mrEvgenX файл один и тот же, просто переименовываю его.

Comment: проверил ваш код - `"date":1600670165,"audio":{"duration":0,"mime_type":"audio/mpeg","file_id":"CQACAgIAAxkDAAILR19oSdUEdMxABRObCTYOdM7UplXCAAKICAACSbhJSx2Av97sOo0KGwQ","file_unique_id":"AgADiAgAAkm4SUs","file_size":22}`

Comment: @D.Violet Интересно. Но я вижу что у вас duration какой-то странный и размер файла тоже. Файл который я отправляю "file_size":4386409
Вы с какой ОС это проделывали?

Comment: нулевой файл, Win10x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробовал запустить этот же скрипт с отправкой файла с русским именем через стандартную консоль в windows

```
python send.py
```

Все заработало.

Comment: забавно, но я проверял в pycharm)

Comment: Видимо я что-то криво установил :|